# How does differ performance of neural network in TensorFlow and Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am novice in Machine Learning (ML) and I'm trying to implement algorithm to understand basic syntax of ML frameworks etc. Now I am working on MNIST database of handwritten digits dataset.

I implemented just one layer (I mean: Input layer has 784 inputs, Hidden layer has 512 nodes, Output layer has 10 outputs) Neural Network using TensorFlow framework, no data preprocessing, 128 batch size, 10 epochs, ADAM optimizer. And the algorithm achieved about 0.95 accuracy on train set.

After that I tried to implement exactly the same architecture in Keras. However, the accuracy (train set) is about 0.3. I tried to find many different implementations founded on the internet but I still cannot find where is the issue. I believe that it is something stupid (as always is) :-/

I presume that the same architecture in Keras should give the same results as the implementation in TensorFlow, am I correct?

My Keras implementation is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

df_train = pd.read_csv('datasets/MNIST_train.csv', delimiter=',', header=0)
Y_train, X_train = np.split(df_train.values, [1], axis=1)

m, n_x = X_train.shape
n_y = len(np.unique(Y_train))
n_layer1 = 512
batch_size = 128
num_epochs = 10

Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train)

X_input = Input(shape=(n_x,), name='input')
X = Dense(n_layer1, activation='relu', name='hidden')(X_input)
X = Dense(n_y, activation='softmax', name='output')(X)

model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X, name='Neural Network')

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```

My TensorFlow implementation is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

def one_hot(a, num_classes):
  return np.eye(num_classes)[a.reshape(-1)]

def get_minibatches(batch_size, m, X, Y):
    output_batches = []

    for index in range(0, m, batch_size):
        index_end = index + batch_size
        batch = [X[index:index_end], Y[index:index_end]]
        output_batches.append(batch)

    return output_batches

def dense_layer(input, channels_in, channels_out, activation=None):
   initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
   w = tf.Variable(initializer([channels_in, channels_out]), name="w")
   b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, channels_out]), name="b")

   if (activation == 'relu'):
       a = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, w) + b)
       return a
   else:
       z = tf.matmul(input, w) + b
       return z

df_train = pd.read_csv('datasets/MNIST_train.csv', delimiter=',', header=0)
Y_train, X_train = np.split(df_train.values, [1], axis=1)

m, n_x = X_train.shape
n_y = len(np.unique(Y_train))
n_layer1 = 512
batch_size = 128
num_epochs = 10

Y_train = one_hot(Y_train, n_y)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_x], name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_y], name="Y")

hidden = dense_layer(X, n_x, n_layer1, 'relu')
output = dense_layer(hidden, n_layer1, n_y)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=output, labels=Y))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

predict = tf.argmax(output, 1)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(predict, tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

minibatches = get_minibatches(batch_size, m, X_train, Y_train)

with tf.Session() as sess:        
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    current_cost = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})
    train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})
    print('Epoch: {:<4} - Loss: {:<8.3} Train Accuracy: {:<5.3} '.format(0, current_cost, train_accuracy))

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):            
        for minibatch in minibatches:
            minibatch_X, minibatch_Y = minibatch

            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={ X: minibatch_X, Y: minibatch_Y })

        current_cost = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})
        train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})
        print('Epoch: {:<4} - Loss: {:<8.3} Train Accuracy: {:<5.3} '.format(epoch + 1, current_cost, train_accuracy))
```

Could you help me and advice what I am doing wrong?
Thank you
Petr

Comment: Could you also include the TF implementation? Would it be possible to load the MNIST dataset from TF (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/))?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the very same *data* in both cases, i.e. `MNIST_train.csv`?

Comment: I added the TF implementation. It makes sense that the "issue" could be there. I did not load the data set from TF datasets. I wanted also to try to load data from CSF file to be able to use the knowledge for another datasets in CSV files.

Comment: I am sure I am using the same dataset (the same CSV file). I am not using any seed value. So of course both implementations differ during learning process which is influenced by randomness (variable initialization, batch selection etc.). However, I ran both implementations several times and both stable differ by about 0.5 accuracy. Which seems odd to me and I feel I did something wrong ... :-/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. At least partially. I standardized the input ((x - xmean) / xstd) and the Keras implementation has been started to return similar results as TensorFlow implementation…